# How to get extra information when calling jpa method in spring 4

Tags: spring-mvc, jpa, spring-boot

Table

```
table_supplier_bills - bill_id, supplier_id, date
```

Model

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "table_supplier_bills")
public class SupplierBill {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="bill_id")
    private Integer billId;

    @Column(name="supplier_id")
    private Integer supplierId;

    @Column(name="date")
    private String date;

    @Column(name="bill_amount")
    @Transient
    private BigDecimal billAmount;

    @Column(name="paid_amount")
    @Transient
    private BigDecimal paidAmount;

    public SupplierBill() {
        super();
    }

    public Integer getBillId() {
        return billId;
    }

    public void setBillId(Integer billId) {
        this.billId = billId;
    }

    public Integer getSupplierId() {
        return supplierId;
    }

    public void setSupplierId(Integer supplierId) {
        this.supplierId = supplierId;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public BigDecimal getBillAmount() {
        return billAmount;
    }

    public void setBillAmount(BigDecimal billAmount) {
        this.billAmount = billAmount;
    }

    public BigDecimal getPaidAmount() {
        return paidAmount;
    }

    public void setPaidAmount(BigDecimal paidAmount) {
        this.paidAmount = paidAmount;
    }
]
```

Repository

```
@Query(value = "SELECT SB.bill_id, SB.date, SB.supplier_id,  SUM(SBD.quantity * SBD.rate) as bill_amount,  COALESCE((SELECT SUM(SBPD.payment_amount) FROM table_supplier_bill_payment_details SBPD WHERE SBD.bill_id = SBPD.bill_id ),0.00) as paid_amount from table_supplier_bills SB INNER JOIN table_supplier_bill_details SBD ON SB.bill_id = SBD.bill_id WHERE SB.supplier_id = ?1 group by SBD.bill_id ORDER BY SB.bill_id DESC" , nativeQuery = true)
List<SupplierBill> getSupplierBills(Integer sid);
```

When i call above method I am not getting bill_amount and paid_amount from service. If i remove @Transient it works but then i am not able to call

```
supplierBillRepository.save(supplierBill);
```

Because it complain that unknown column bill_amount and paid_amount.

What changes i need to do, so it works with both the method?

Comment: you mean those fields that are not persisted (marked with `@Transient`) ? and you're surprised that it doesn't find them in the datastore?

Answer (score 0):

All of the **non-persistent fields should be marked as `@Transient`**, so `save()` will work only when you mark those fields as `@Transient`.

The aggregation fields from `getSupplierBills()` method can be fetched by defining a separate DTO class like `SupplierBillResults` as shown below:

```
public class SupplierBillResults {

        private final Date date;

        private final Integer billId;

        private final Integer supplierId;

        private final BigDecimal billAmount;

        private final BigDecimal paidAmount;

        public SupplierBillResults(Integer billId, Date date, 
              BigDecimal billAmount, BigDecimal paidAmount, Integer supplierId) {
             //set the fields here
        }

        //Generate getters
}
```

**Query method:**

```
//Add your @Query here
List< SupplierBillResults> getSupplierBillResults(Integer sid);
```

**Note**: You can use the `SupplierBillResults` DTO to carry the data across layers (if you wanted) and you can remove your `@Transient` fields from your `SupplierBill` class, you can handle this as per your requirement.

EDIT Repository code

```
@Repository
public interface SupplierBillRepository extends JpaRepository<SupplierBill, Integer> {
    @Query(value = "SELECT SB.bill_id, SB.date, SB.supplier_id,  SUM(SBD.quantity * SBD.rate) as bill_amount,  COALESCE((SELECT SUM(SBPD.payment_amount) FROM table_supplier_bill_payment_details SBPD WHERE SBD.bill_id = SBPD.bill_id ),0.00) as paid_amount from table_supplier_bills SB INNER JOIN table_supplier_bill_details SBD ON SB.bill_id = SBD.bill_id WHERE SB.supplier_id = ?1 group by SBD.bill_id ORDER BY SB.bill_id DESC" , nativeQuery = true)
    List< SupplierBillResults> getSupplierBillResults(Integer sid);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. After making the changes suggested by you Now i am getting this error - No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.Integer] to type [com.example.model.SupplierBillResults]